# Hybrid app: Trying to use a ListView to show values from the HTML

Tags: android, html, view, android-listview

I have  a webApp which I need to convert partly to native. I have a list of values I'm fetching from the HTML and need to show it in Android as a ListView.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: use Adapter to set values in listviews